# Is the area of a triangle is less than that of its mean triangle of equal area?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

**Definitions**: We generate random triangles using various distribution (uniform, gaussian etc) for $\theta$ to get the polar coordinates of the vertices $\cos \theta,\sin \theta$ in a circle of radius $r = 1$ and define:

- **Ordered mean-triangle of equal area**: Let $a_x, b_x$ and $c_x$ be mean of the smallest, the intermediate and the longest side of all triangles of area $x$. The triangle with sides $a_x, b_x$ and $c_x$ is called the ordered mean-trinagle of equal area $x$.
- **Random mean-triangle of equal area**: Let $p_x, q_x$ and $r_x$ be mean of the side taken in no particular order of all triangles of area $x$. The triangle with sides $a_x, b_x$ and $c_x$ is the random mean-trinagle of equal area $x$.

Let $\Delta_{a,b,c}$ be the area of a triangle of sides $a,b$ and $c$. Experimental data shows that, the area of both the ordered mean-triangle and the random mean-triangle is greater than that of $x$. More specifically, we have
$$
x \le \Delta_{a_x,b_x,c_x} \le \Delta_{p_x,q_x,r_x} \tag 1
$$

with equality occuring only if $x = 0$ or $\displaystyle x = \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$. The graph below plots the area $x$ in the $X$-axis and the differences $\Delta_{a_x,b_x,c_x} - x$ and $\Delta_{p_x,q_x,r_x} - x$ on the $Y$-axis.

[image]

**Question**: Is the area of a triangle is less than that of its mean triangle of equal area?

Comment: If you do not give a precise procedure to define the construction of "all the triangles", then this problem may be ill defined because of the "Bertrand paradox" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Comment: @Quillo Actually, I am aware of this. I generated the triangles randomly using different distribution (uniform, gaussian etc) for $\theta$ to get the coordinates of the vertices $r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta$. What I observed is that the inequality holds regardless of the distribution or even if we fix one vertex of the triangle. So I think this problem is not impacted by Bertrand's paradox.

Comment: The excess area of the random mean triangle is reasonable. Because all three side are means of randomly selected size, the expected length of all three will be the same, so the mean values obtained will be nearly the same for all three.. An equilateral triangle minimizes the ratio of perimeter to area among all triangles, The various actual triangles will include many with two vertices close together and the third distant. These triangles have a very high perimeter for the area, making the mean perimeter much larger than equilateral triangle of that area.